# How to access Transfer Accelerated S3 bucket using Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I have a powershell script that works when accessing a normal S3 bucket but if i change the bucket name to the Transfer Accelerated bucket name then it gives an error "Bucket not found".

Including the script that works with a commented out bucketname that doesn't work.

```
# Your account access key - must have read access to your S3 Bucket
$accessKey = "KEY"
# Your account secret access key
$secretKey = "SECRETKEY"
# 
$region = "us-east-1"
# The name of your S3 Bucket
$bucket = "myBucket"
#The above works!! - but if i comment out the above and uncomment 
the below line then it no longer works.
#$bucket = "myBucket.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com"

# The folder in your bucket to copy, including trailing slash. Leave 
blank to copy the entire bucket
$keyPrefix = "myFolder/"
# The local file path where files should be copied
$localPath = "D:\S3_Files\myFolder\"

$objects = Get-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -KeyPrefix $keyPrefix - 
AccessKey $accessKey -SecretKey $secretKey -Region $region

foreach($object in $objects) {
    $localFileName = $object.Key -replace $keyPrefix, ''
    if ($localFileName -ne '') {
        $localFilePath = Join-Path $localPath $localFileName
        Copy-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $object.Key -LocalFile $localFilePath -AccessKey $accessKey -SecretKey $secretKey -Region $region
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code, could it be a permissions issue? from my understanding you have to be the owner of the bucket to access transfer acceleration.

Comment: Do you get any error message returned or does it appear that nothing happens? If nothing, do you have access to Wireshark/Postman/Fiddler so you can watch the traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying the s3-accelerate name for your bucket, just use the regular bucket name and add the **-UseAccelerateEndpoint** switch to your S3 commands. The cmdlets will then target the accelerated S3 endpoints for you.